# A partition is necessary before installing ubuntu on windows 7?

Tags: installation

Im trying to install Ubuntu on my PC that runs Windows 7. Do I need to make a partition before installation?

Comment: The graphic user interface for allocating the necessary partitions is included in the Ubuntu Installer.

Answer (score 0):

in short: YES

you need to make another partition to install Ubuntu.
You can use a live disk with [partition magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) to safely* create an extra partition.

*as long as you defragment your drive to only use the start/end of the drive and don't resize it past the point where you have data stored.